# Jail only a specific user with vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd, account-restrictions, jails

I'm using both Redhat and CentOS. When I do followings:

```
 # vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
 chroot_local_user=YES
 # service vsftpd restart
```

Then all users are jailed in their home directory.

How can I jail a specific user only?

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/nonchroot.list
```

Where file `/etc/vsftpd/nonchroot.list` should contail the users you don’t want to chroot.

OR

```
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot.list
```

Where the file `/etc/vsftpd/chroot.list` should contain the users you want to be chrooted to their home. By default all other users should have access to the / (root).